# console log decimal steps to number in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, numbers

I'm trying to make a tenths `0.1` numbered ruler dynamically in Javascript. I know I can easily make a for loop and `console.log` to get the correct number of iterations. I just gotta get the Math right and this is what's confusing me on how to code.

It's supposed to log like so...

```
0
0.1
0.2
0.3
0.4
0.5
0.6
0.7
0.8
0.9
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
1.4
1.5
1.6
1.7
1.8
1.9
2
```

whole numbers like 0 would just be 0, 1 would be 1, 2 would be 2 and so on....

However my problem is it generates like this...

```
0
.1
.2
.3
.4
.5
.6
.7
.8
.9
.10
.11
.12
.13
.14
.15
.16
.17
.18
.19
.20
```

I know 1.1 is greater than 1 and 2 is greater than 1.0 which I know I can write that expression like `(1.1 > 1)` to detect that but how do I write all the expressions out in the log example expressed in my first example above?

```js
var timeVal = parseFloat(parseFloat(time.value));

for (i = 0; i < parseFloat(timeVal * 10) + 1; i++) {
    if (i === 0) {
      console.log(+i)
    } else if (i <= 1) {
      console.log('.'+i)
    } else {
      console.log('.'+i)
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

seconds: <input id="time" type="number" value="2" min="0" step=".1">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple for loop to do it. It also works for decimal numbers. That "timeVal + 0.01" in the for loop is to avoid problems with the float error margin.

```js
var timeVal = parseFloat(document.getElementById("time").value);

for (var i = 0; i <= timeVal + 0.01; i += 0.1) {
  console.log(i.toFixed(1));
}
```

```html
seconds: <input id="time" type="number" value="2.3" min="0" step=".1">
```